# Type.GetType returns Nothing in SerializationBinder

Tags: vb.net, serialization, type-conversion, deserialization

I am creating a vb.net application which needs to be able to deserialize files that were serialized in a different application as well as serialize files that can be deserialized in that other application.

I am trying to make this work via the use of a SerializationBinder to convert the type during serialize / deserialize.  Using [This article from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.binder?view=netframework-4.8) as a reference, this is what I have at this point....

In my deserialize function:

```
myDeserializer.Binder = New TypeConverter()
openCount = DirectCast(myDeserializer.Deserialize(stream), Count)
```

Then:

```
Class TypeConverter

    Inherits SerializationBinder

    Public Overrides Function BindToType(assemblyName As String, typeName As String) As Type

        Dim returnType As Type = Nothing

        If assemblyName = "[name from other application]" Then
            assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName
        End If

        If typeName = "[other application namespace].Count" Then
            typeName = "Count"
        End If

        returnType = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyName))

        Return returnType

    End Function

End Class
```

The If statements are true, so assemblyName and typeName are getting set correctly.  But returnType is not getting set - it remains Nothing.  And I have no idea why.

Note that I do have all the same classes in both applications (namely Count, which is the type that is serialized / deserialized between them).

Thank you!

Comment: Not for nothing, but you can avoid the problem of sharing data between assemblies by using [Protobuf-Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/) instead of the BinaryFormatter.  Unlike BF, it doesnt encode the assembly-culture-class info into the output

Comment: Is `typeName = "Count"` just for demo purposes?  I believe that typically that it would have a namespace qualifier.  i.e `typeName = "rootNamespace.Count"`

Comment: @TnTinMn - "Count" is the Object Type that is being serialized / deserialized.  When you are referencing an object type within your own namespace you don't have to specify the namespace in front.  I changed the text for "type from other application" that might help make that clearer.

Comment: @Andarta - From the [documentation for Type.GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), "The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. ... If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the **type name qualified by its namespace**."

Comment: @TnTinMn - That does not help with the issue that returnType is not getting set to anything and remaining Nothing.  Also, the type that I am trying to deserialize is from a different assembly...don't I have to make sure the type being returned specifies the assembly I'm running in order to make that work?

Comment: @Andarta - If Type.GetType can not locate the specified type name it returns Nothing.  Have you tried replacing `typeName = "Count"' with `typeName =GetType(Count).FullName"' to see if that works?  Personally, I would restructure your code and replace 'typeName = "Count"` with `Return GetType(Count)` instead of doing a name lookup for a type that you say exists in the current assembly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, well it turns out that in this case (using Type.GetType in this use), it doesn't work unless you specify the namespace before the type.  So where I had `typeName = "Count"` I had to change that to `typeName = "[my project].Count"`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a87che9d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It also turns out that this function repeats for every type coming in (not just specifically what is being deserialized, but for every type of the properties in that).  So being that my "Count" type contains properties that are of other custom types, and also some that are lists of other custom types, I had to make sure each of these is getting properly converted.

Where I am at now is here:  in stepping through the process, it looks like all goes fine.  But after it has converted the first type that is a list of a custom type's structure, then upon trying to convert the next one I get an Argument Exception.

This is the code now:

```
Public Overrides Function BindToType(assemblyName As String, typeName As String) As Type

    If assemblyName.Contains("[other project]") Then
        assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName
    End If

    If typeName.Contains("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[[Other Project].[Type],") Then
           typeName = String.Format("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[[my project].[type]], {0}", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)
    ElseIf typeName.Contains("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[[Other Project].[type]+[structure],") Then
           typeName = String.Format("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[[My project].[Type]+[Structure], {0}", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)
    ElseIf typeName.Contains("[Other Project]") Then
           typeName = Replace(typeName, "[Other Project]", "[My Project]")
    End If

    Return Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyName))

 End Function
```

So the *System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[[My project].[Type]+[Structure]* is a list of a custom type's structure.  The first one that it comes to seems to convert fine, but then when trying to convert whatever is next, I get this:

> Additional information: Object of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.TypeLoadExceptionHolder' cannot be
>   converted to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[My Project.Type+Structure]'.

The Type and Structure in this case being the type that was previously converted...not the type that is currently being converted when this exception is thrown.

No idea what is going on here....

Comment: Well, I'm blind...it turns out the issue was that I was missing a couple brackets at the end in each of the statements to convert a list of something.
Ex:  Change:    
"typeName = String.Format("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[[my project].[type]], {0}", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)"

To:
    "typeName = String.Format("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[[my project].[type]], {0}]]", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)"

WHY I didn't get an error until after it tried to convert a list of a structure specifically and everything before that seemed to work, I have NO IDEA.