# Convert Structure in SerializationBinder

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, deserialization

Is there something special that needs to be done in order to convert a structure within a SerializationBinder?

Refer to my original question and "answer" to that:  [Type.GetType returns Nothing in SerializationBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521389/type-gettype-returns-nothing-in-serializationbinder)

The first time it comes to a list of a structure, I get:

> Object of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.TypeLoadExceptionHolder'
>   cannot be converted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm blind...it turns out the issue was that I was missing a couple brackets at the end in each of the statements to convert a list of something.

Ex:  Change:

```
typeName = String.Format("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[[my project].[type]], {0}", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)
```

To:

```
typeName = String.Format("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[[my project].[type]], {0}]]", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)
```

WHY I didn't get an error until after it tried to convert a list of a structure specifically and everything before that seemed to work, I have NO IDEA.